# How to search for all points inside multi polygons which have intersect?

Tags: mysql, geospatial

I am working with spatial object in MySQL.  I have a table that saves the location of estate in database as "longitude" and "latitude", and I search for these estates inside of polygons that user requests.  I am using the `st_contains` function in MySQL, like this:

```
select * from estate where ST_CONTAINS(GEOMFROMTEXT(region),POINT(plat,plon)));
```

In the code snippet **region** has this format:

```
"POLYGON((lat1 lng1,lat2 lng2,lat3 lng3,lat4 lng4,lat1 lng1),(lat6 lng6,lat7 lng7,lat8 lng8,lat9 lng9,lat6 lng6))"
```

Everything works well when polygons have no overlap with each other.  However, if polygons have overlap, MySQL subtracts that overlap area and does not retrieve estates in the overlap area.  I add this image for more explanation:

[image]

How do I make this search work correctly, even with overlapped polygons?

Comment: I found this (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/search/?d=12&p=1&q=polygon) documentation about Polygon in mysql. this describe my mistake... now i am searching for a method for searching inside of multiple   polygons

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In MySQL, we have the type `MULTIPOLYGON` for this situation.  You can see complete document in [`MySQL` Spatial Data Types](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mysql-spatial-data-types.php).

Your `region` will need to be defined like this:

```
"MULTIPOLYGON(((lat1 lng1,lat2 lng2,lat3 lng3,lat4 lng4,lat1 lng1)),((lat6 lng6,lat7 lng7,lat8 lng8,lat9 lng9,lat6 lng6)))"
```

Comment: i am crying now ..... i saw my hero today and i am so far far away from you.... this is a emotion full moment